# Websphere JNDI lookup fails

Tags: tomcat, websphere, jndi

I am getting below error when I am looking up a JNDI connection for jdbc datasource:

javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".]

My lookup code is inside a static method. Is that the reason for this error. I am not creating any threads

It works in tomcat without any issue

Thanks for your help

Code I am using is something like below:

```
  javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
  Context cxt = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/");
```

Stacktrace:

```
C1APP522   2    2013-07-01 21:57:18,332 ERROR DBUtil get EnvContext failed
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:428)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:160)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getEnvContext(DBUtil_Ext.java:121)
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getDataSource(DBUtil_Ext.java:102)
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getConnection(DBUtil_Ext.java:70)
    at com.test.integration.IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.send(IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.java:107)
    at com.test.integration.IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.send(IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.gs)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.test.system.integration.plugins.PluginProxy.invoke(PluginProxy.java:66)
    at $Proxy58.send(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.test.system.integration.plugins.PluginCallTraceImpl$PluginCallTraceHandler.invoke(PluginCallTraceImpl.java:61)
    at $Proxy58.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter$2.run(MessageWriter.java:347)
    at com.test.system.transaction.ScopedUserTransaction.run(ScopedUserTransaction.java:54)
    at com.test.system.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.execute(TransactionManagerImpl.java:111)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.AckHelper.executeMessageOperation(AckHelper.java:137)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.AckHelper.executeMessageOperation(AckHelper.java:121)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter.executeSendAndAfterSendInTxn(MessageWriter.java:332)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter.sendNextMessage(MessageWriter.java:272)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.trySendMessage(MessageSenderRunnable.java:52)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.send(MessageSenderRunnable.java:42)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.run(MessageSenderRunnable.java:30)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter$CatchesExceptionRunnable.run(MessageWriter.java:603)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    ... 37 more
C1APP522        2013-07-01 21:57:18,332 ERROR Messaging Exception in MessageSenderRunnable
java.lang.RuntimeException: get EnvContext failed
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getEnvContext(DBUtil_Ext.java:125)
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getDataSource(DBUtil_Ext.java:102)
    at com.test.integration.database.DBUtil_Ext.getConnection(DBUtil_Ext.java:70)
    at com.test.integration.IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.send(IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.java:107)
    at com.test.integration.IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.send(IntegrationTransportPlugin_Ext.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.test.system.integration.plugins.PluginProxy.invoke(PluginProxy.java:66)
    at $Proxy58.send(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.test.system.integration.plugins.PluginCallTraceImpl$PluginCallTraceHandler.invoke(PluginCallTraceImpl.java:61)
    at $Proxy58.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter$2.run(MessageWriter.java:347)
    at com.test.system.transaction.ScopedUserTransaction.run(ScopedUserTransaction.java:54)
    at com.test.system.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.execute(TransactionManagerImpl.java:111)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.AckHelper.executeMessageOperation(AckHelper.java:137)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.AckHelper.executeMessageOperation(AckHelper.java:121)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter.executeSendAndAfterSendInTxn(MessageWriter.java:332)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter.sendNextMessage(MessageWriter.java:272)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.trySendMessage(MessageSenderRunnable.java:52)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.send(MessageSenderRunnable.java:42)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageSenderRunnable.run(MessageSenderRunnable.java:30)
    at com.test.system.integration.messaging.dispatch.MessageWriter$CatchesExceptionRunnable.run(MessageWriter.java:603)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: In the context of what Java EE component the lookup is being made?

Comment: Its a jdbc data source that I am looking up

Comment: Show us the entire code path

Comment: @sab I am asking not WHAT is being looked up, but WHERE this is being done. Is your lookup code invoked from servlet or something? Data source must be bound into local component (whatever it is) namespace, as you use "java:/comp/env" namespace which depends on the context (component).

Comment: @fnt, sorry. This is being looked up by a component that I don't have access to source but it is some batch mechanism and I think it uses a executor framework. I added stacktrace if that helps

Comment: @sab Then, who invokes that third-party component? 'java:comp/env' can only be used from within component running inside JEE environment. Could it be that with Tomcat you have a piece of configuration that binds your data source into local namespace ('java:comp/env/your_datasource_name')?

Comment: @fnt, I am deploying the exact same war in tomcat. In context.xml I have this: <Resource   name="jndi/testtables"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="50"
    maxIdle="50"
    maxWait="20000"
    username="user"
    password="pass12"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=intdb"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="1800"
 />

Comment: @fnt,also does it matter if I have /comp/env vs comp/env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have data source configured in WAS, you have two options:

a. During deployment bind data source into calling component's namespace and use the name starting with 'java:comp/env/' for lookup. For example, to bind data source for the whole web application you should add the following to web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>name_used_in_lookup</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>data_source_jndi_name</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

name_used_in_lookup should be without 'java:comp/env/' part.

b. Look up data source directly by its JNDI name without using 'java:comp/env/'

Comment: Can you help me with the first option. How do I bind it in websphere. Can I configure it somewhere in admin console